# Phase portraits of multiply connected n-dimensional state-spaces

Tags: differential-geometry, control-theory, nonlinear-system

I ask for help in my attempts to understand the following question.

There is an n-dimensional nonlinear state-space of the following form:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*sin(t) - sin(t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{y} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*1.1sin(2t) - 1.1sin(2t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{z} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*1.2sin(3t) - 1.3sin(3t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$

There is a rule according to which the dynamic features of the system can be estimated by constructing the C (n, 2) phase planes of combinations of variables of the state space.

${C_{{2}}}^{n}=1/2\,{\frac {n}{ \left( n-2 \right) !}}$

In the article [On the n-Dimensional Phase Portraits](https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/9/5/872/pdf) state-space is divided into pairs of equations that are combinations of different variable states, and phase planes are constructed for these combinations.
What if several state variables are included in these pairs of states? 
For example, a paired combination of state-space variables would be the following equation:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*sin(t) - sin(t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{y} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*1.1sin(2t) - 1.1sin(2t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$

For me, this is like solving a system of two equations with the number of variables greater than 2.

I realized that first need to deal with the mathematical side of the issue.

1. How build phase portraits for an n-dimensional state space if it is non-autonomous (time-varying sinusoidal signals are included in the system)?
2. Is it possible to solve the problem by evaluating the closedness of a 1-form and determining the linear dependence / independence of 1-forms for the corresponding pair of Pfaff equations?

I assume that the expression

$x^2 + y^2 + z^2$

can be divided into sums of variables and write pairs of equations in the following form and investigate them already, for example, introducing, therefore, new state variables.

$\begin{cases} \dot{X} = (x^2 + y^2)*sin(t) - sin(t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{Y} = (x^2 + y^2)*1.1sin(2t) - 1.1sin(2t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$

$\begin{cases} \dot{Y} = (y^2 + z^2)*1.1sin(2t) - 1.1sin(2t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{Z} = (y^2 + z^2)*1.2sin(3t) - 1.2sin(3t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$

Are my arguments true?

Comment: How? As far as i know, Mathematica can do this numerically. I want to understand the analytical side and general principles.

Comment: Yes, i want to understand how to work with the state-space for such systems in general.
I tried your code, but the resulting vector field is uninformative.
We need to find a way to get more information.
Something like this.
https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/14160/plotting-a-phase-portrait

Comment: Is it possible to study the system for 5.6 state variables in this way?
Do we have to divide the system into "triplets"?

Comment: "You can always solve those equations numerically and plot them in pairs"
I am in a slight confusion at this moment.
Because the systems of equations are 2, and the variables are 3 (due to the component $x^2 + y^2 + z^2$.

Comment: You mean, solve the state-space numerically using Mathematica (even if the number of state variables is more than 3), and then combine them in pairs or three, using the graphical tools of Mathematica and see what happens?
Did i understand you correctly?

Comment: This approach, apparently, is the most true.
I still want to understand the analytical side, but I don’t know if this is possible at all.
Because it difficult to evaluate the influence of the parameters of equations (amplitude and frequency of sinusoidal oscillations).

Comment: The problem of that article, the link to which i attached in my post, is that the structure of the state-space there is such that any pair combination of equations includes two state variables.
To investigate in a similar way from this article a combination of equations like this is not possible i think, only numerically:

$\begin{cases} \dot{x} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*sin(t) - sin(t+\pi/2) \\ \dot{y} = (x^2 + y^2 + z^2)*1.1sin(2t) - 1.1sin(2t+\pi/2) \end{cases}$

Comment: Thank you, Moo! I will try it. If you are interested in these results, we can later discuss these results in correspondence.
I wish you a good and successful day!